# Keep active a list item with ngfor after clicking

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have following html code part which is implemented with Angular, Typescript. I cannot keep items active after clicking.

```
   <li *ngFor="let permission of tempPermission"  class="MenuLink"
        (click)="onSelect(permission)">
    <span>{{permission.id}}</span> {{permission.name}}
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggzg5b?file=src/app/app.component.css) As a way use one more attribute in model such as clicked and use ngClass to add class due to this clicked attribute

```
<li *ngFor="let permission of tempPermission"  class="MenuLink"[ngClass]="permission.clicked ? 'clicked':''" (click)="onSelect(permission)">
  <span>{{permission.id}}</span> {{permission.name}}
</li>
```

in component

```
onSelect(item){
    this.tempPermission.forEach(elem=>{elem.clicked=false})
    item.clicked=true;
    // your process
  }
```

in css

```
.clicked{
  background: gray;
  color:white
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  my onSelect method is following.    public onSelect(permission: Permission): void {
        console.log(permission.name);
        this.selectedPermission1 = permission;
        
    } therefore how can I access the click attribute since Permission type has not such attribute?